# ThreadAbortException not catched properly in WebMethod

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have to redirect from `WebMethod` and I know I can't. So I am just trying to return page url as string and will redirect in `success` callback.

Problem is I have huge amount of code before redirection and that is written in one centralized method (only method that is called before redirect to perform same operation before that.) In my redirection also, I have to call that function.

I am simply putting my code here without calling centralized function for better understanding.

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public static string TestException()
    {
        try
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Test.aspx");
            return "No Exception";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return "Exception";
        }

    }
```

in response I am getting `Internal Server Error (505)` with `System.Threading.ThreadAbortException` instead of returning "Exception" as in catch block.

This is not the case with other exceptions, i.e. if I replace `Response.Redirect` with something like

```
int i = 0;
int j = 5/i;
```

It also raises exception but doesn't give me `Internal Server Error (505)`, instead return "Excetion" i.e. returned string from catch block.

My questions are

1. Why it is treating `System.Threading.ThreadAbortException` differently from other exceptions?
2. I know other work around like function over loading and optional parameters to be used in `Centralized` function and by checking additional parameter I can return string instead of redirect but I want to know if there is anything that I can use inside webmethod or any other place without touching centralized function to get it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why it is treating System.Threading.ThreadAbortException differently
>   from other exceptions?

For your first question, From [ThreadAbortException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_4) on MSDN:

> ThreadAbortException is a **special exception** that **can be caught**, **but it
>   will automatically be raised again at the end of the catch block**. When
>   this exception is raised, the runtime executes all the finally blocks
>   before ending the thread. Because the thread can do an unbounded
>   computation in the finally blocks or call Thread.ResetAbort to cancel
>   the abort, there is no guarantee that the thread will ever end. If you
>   want to wait until the aborted thread has ended, you can call the
>   Thread.Join method. Join is a blocking call that does not return until
>   the thread actually stops executing.

I think to prevent that, you need to call `Thread.ResetAbort()` in the catch block.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static string TestException()
{
    try
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Test.aspx");
        return "No Exception";
    }
    catch(ThreadAbortException ex)
    {
        Thread.ResetAbort();
        return "Exception";
    }

}
```

And using Response.Redirect in a `WEB METHOD` isn't a good practice! When you are using `WEB METHOD` you should follow `SOAP` rules. And you need to know calling `Response.Redirect` will call `Response.End`.

[HttpResponse.Redirect Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.80).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_2) page at MSDN:

> An absolute URL (for example, http://www.contoso.com/default.aspx) or
>   a relative URL (for example, default.aspx) can be specified for the
>   target location but some browsers may reject a relative URL. **Redirect**
>   **calls End which raises a ThreadAbortException exception** upon
>   completion.

Comment: Give `Authentication failed` error on console after using `Thread.ResetAbort`

Comment: @Imad Trust me, Using `HttpRedirect` isn't really a good practice. I suggest you no to do it.

Comment: Agreed upon it long back. wanted to still *try* it.

Comment: It doesn't work. I accepted it because I found it good explanation.

Comment: If this is bad practice, what is good practice? Can you provide an example of following SOAP rules for a redirect?